# tikz cannot parse radius in "radius=0.3" command

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw (0,1.7) circle [radius=0.3] node {$T_1$}; 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I just wanted to specify the radius of the circle, but tikz gave the error

> "! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this radius."

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please show us a complete example (as minimal as possible) which results in this error!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Done.

Comment: You should now delete all packages which you do not need here and you will have a perfect MWE. I think, deleting everything but `\usepackage{tikz}` will show the same thing. Note that you load this twice. You are having some dups in there. `graphics` is kinda old -- just leave `graphicx`. `hyperref` should be the last package in most cases.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Done again. :)

Comment: I get no error either with the reduced MWE or the full one in the previous version. Can you tell what TeX distribution you're running?

Comment: If you are using PGF version 2.0, you should write `circle(0.3)` instead of `circle [radius=0.3]`.

Comment: @AboAmmar Thanks, that works! Can you make it into an answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about outdated package syntax (`pgf` v2.0, current version is v3.0).